# Converting string to a formatted date

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am trying to convert a string to proper date format using Java's `SimpleDateFormat`. For some reason, it's not working with certain months like "Mar", "May", "Oct", and "Dec." Can somebody help me? It works fine for all other months.

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xpath.regex.ParseException;

public class test {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws java.text.ParseException {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat parse = new SimpleDateFormat("dd. MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss");
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

            //why this doesn't work with certain months like Mar, May, Oct, and Dec? otherwise it works fine

            String dateTime =   "01. Jun 2010 15:30:32";
            //String dateTime = "07. Mar 2011 15:20:10";
            //String dateTime = "07. May 2011 15:20:10";
            //String dateTime = "07. Oct 2011 15:20:10";
            //String dateTime = "07. Dec 2011 15:20:10";


            java.util.Date parsed =parse.parse(dateTime);
            System.out.println("formatted: " + formatter.format(parsed));
        } catch(ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("Caught " + e);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried running your code and it worked perfectly for me.  What is the issue you faced?  BTW, you should be catching `java.text.ParseException` and not `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xpath.regex.ParseException`

Comment: Add `com.sun.*` package to ignore list in IDE autosuggest list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the locale on `SimpleDateFormat`, otherwise the platform default locale will be used for month names. You can do that by passing it as [2nd argument to the `SimpleDateFormat` constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale%29). If you want to work with English formatted month names, pass [`Locale.ENGLISH`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#ENGLISH).

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd. MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

---

By the way, you can learn about your platform default locale by

```
System.out.println(Locale.getDefault());
```

This is configureable at OS level (in Windows control panel, for example) and as JVM argument.

Comment: You're welcome. Since you're new here, don't forget to mark the answer accepted whenever it helped in answering the question. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.